# Using Heroku to launch an application, and running into an error

Tags: python, heroku, psycopg2

The error message I'm receiving in my terminal is the below:

11:56:06 AM web.1 |import psycopg2_binary as psycopg2
11:56:06 AM web.1 |  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2_binary'

From my hours I've spent trying to resolve this is suggests that the application can't find psycopg2_binary.
I've tried numerous attempts at solutions, but no luck.

Any advice would be appreciated - I can share more details on the code if necessary.

TIA!

Here is a summary of the methods I tried to resolve the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2_binary' issue:

1. Installing psycopg2-binary: We suggested installing the psycopg2-binary package using pip install psycopg2-binary. This package provides a binary distribution of psycopg2 and can be used as a replacement.
2. Changing import statements: We suggested changing the import statement from import psycopg2_binary as psycopg2 to import psycopg2. This is because the psycopg2-binary package provides the psycopg2 module, so there is no need to import it as psycopg2_binary.
3. Checking Python environment: We checked the Python environment using python -m pip show psycopg2-binary to verify if psycopg2-binary is installed in the myenv Anaconda environment.
4. Running in a new Anaconda environment: We attempted to run the application in a new Anaconda environment (myenv) to ensure that the correct Python interpreter and environment are being used.

Despite trying these methods, the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2_binary' issue still persists.

I will note, that I'm now using Poetry and not a requirements.txt file. I've ensured I've added the dependency to Poetry.

Following the comment below...

For some reason, import psycopg2 or import psycopg2 both weren't included on my imports at the top. However, I ran pip install psycopg2 (which is already in my poetry dependencies file) and it gave me this error:
pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.9.7.tar.gz (383 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
Building wheel for psycopg2 (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for psycopg2 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psycopg2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

it seems to fail when it 'builds wheel for psycopg2'.

Any thoughts?

Error Traceback:

```
    0xzohan@zohan-MBP Serverlang % heroku local 
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
2:12:07 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:07 +0100] [80592] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2:12:07 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:07 +0100] [80592] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5001 (80592)
2:12:07 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:07 +0100] [80592] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2:12:07 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:07 +0100] [80594] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 80594
2:12:12 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:12 +0100] [80594] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2:12:12 PM web.1 |  Traceback (most recent call last):
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      worker.init_process()
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      self.load_wsgi()
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2:12:12 PM web.1 |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      self.callable = self.load()
2:12:12 PM web.1 |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      return self.load_wsgiapp()
2:12:12 PM web.1 |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2:12:12 PM web.1 |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2:12:12 PM web.1 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2:12:12 PM web.1 |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/0xzohan/Serverlang/main.py", line 15, in <module>
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      from database import create_user_table
2:12:12 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/0xzohan/Serverlang/database.py", line 3, in <module>
2:12:12 PM web.1 |      import psycopg2_binary as psycopg2
2:12:12 PM web.1 |  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2_binary'
2:12:12 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:12 +0100] [80594] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 80594)
2:12:12 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:12 +0100] [80592] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2:12:12 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:12:12 +0100] [80592] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
2:12:12 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

Next Error Code with change of line import psycopg2_binary as psycopg2 which should be just import psycopg2

```
    0xzohan@Harrys-MBP Serverlang % heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
2:24:12 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:12 +0100] [81581] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2:24:13 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:12 +0100] [81581] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5001 (81581)
2:24:13 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:12 +0100] [81581] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2:24:13 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:12 +0100] [81582] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 81582
2:24:16 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:16 +0100] [81582] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2:24:16 PM web.1 |  Traceback (most recent call last):
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      worker.init_process()
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      self.load_wsgi()
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2:24:16 PM web.1 |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      self.callable = self.load()
2:24:16 PM web.1 |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      return self.load_wsgiapp()
2:24:16 PM web.1 |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2:24:16 PM web.1 |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2:24:16 PM web.1 |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2:24:16 PM web.1 |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/0xzohan/Serverlang/main.py", line 15, in <module>
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      from database import create_user_table
2:24:16 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/0xzohan/Serverlang/database.py", line 3, in <module>
2:24:16 PM web.1 |      import psycopg2
2:24:16 PM web.1 |  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
2:24:16 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:16 +0100] [81582] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 81582)
2:24:17 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:17 +0100] [81581] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2:24:17 PM web.1 |  [2023-09-14 14:24:17 +0100] [81581] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
2:24:17 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

Comment: The import statement is `import psycopg2`, not `import psycopg2_binary`.

Comment: I just edited my original message to respond to your comment

Comment: Can you share the complete error traceback please?

Comment: The error message I get from terminal is over 2000 words long... Is this what you're after?

Comment: added above - lmk thoughts - the traceback is much smaller than the psycopg2 failing to install haha

Comment: This is your code, right? `/Users/0xzohan/Serverlang/database.py`.  It seems to contain this line `import psycopg2_binary as psycopg2` which should be just `import psycopg2`

Comment: I changed the code in Database.py from import psycopg2_binary as psycopg2 to  just import psycopg2, and now I'm receiving the same error code (by the looks of it) - any thoughts? thanks for ur help so far.

Comment: So that import statement is correct, but apparently neither `psycopg2` nor `psycopg2-binary` is installed in the environment where your code is executing.  I can't do much more to help you - the issue is definitely in the environment - but I will observe that if you are running in an anaconda environment you may need to use conda to install your deps  (but I could be wrong about that)

Comment: Heroku's official Python buildpack doesn't support Poetry _or_ Anaconda. But it looks like you're just trying to run this locally? Do you actually plan to deploy to Heroku? Why are you using Poetry and Anaconda together?